# Delphi - How to change t chart series's colourpalette?

Tags: delphi, teechart, delphi-10.3-rio

I have an TAreaGraph with

```
(series[0] as tareaseries).coloreachpoint := true;
with chart1 do
    series[0].addXY( {the x-value} , {the y-value}, {name} , clTeeColor);
end;
```

So now, the bars, or points, are all different colours, but i hate the colour palette.
I saw in the object inspector, there is an option when adding a new series and selecting the type, to change the colour palette to Mac Os.

I have tried everything to do this at runtime, because I am adding the series dynamically, to no avail.
Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Regards,
Romans.

Comment: *I have tried everything*, but you don't show a single thing you've tried.

Comment: I am referring to just randomly typing possible names for methods or properties. My apologies if that was unclear.

Comment: After using the designer view the form as text to see what property is set and to what. To view a form as text right click on it in the designer and near the bottom is an entry for _view as text_. To get back right click again and _view as form_ is in the middle of the menu.

Comment: So, in stead of random trial and error, maybe create your own palette as an array of `TColor`, where each entry is a combination of BGR color components. E.g. $FFFFFF for white, $FF0000 for blue, $00FF00 for lime, $0000FF for red. Or use ready made color constants like `clCream ($F0FBFF)` and others. Then in `series[0].addXY()` replace `clTeeColor` with a color from your own palette. You get exactly the result you write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting a chart on a form and changing the palette to iOS then viewing the form as text gives:

```
  object Chart1: TChart
    Left = 176
    Top = 136
    Width = 400
    Height = 250
    Title.Text.Strings = (
      'TChart')
    TabOrder = 0
    DefaultCanvas = 'TGDIPlusCanvas'
    ColorPaletteIndex = 18
  end
```

So the property is ColorPaletteIndex and for the iOS color palette you would use 18. There might be an enumeration with nice values somewhere but the number will work fine.

```
  chart1.ColorPaletteIndex := 18;
```

Comment: Hello, Brian. How do you view it as text? I would like to know so that I could check if I have similar question in the future.

Comment: @Romans right click on the form with the chart, in the menu that comes up there should be a ''View as Text" near the bottom. Right clicking in the text there will be a "View as form" in the middle to get back. Look through the text for the object you are looking for what properties to set etc.